# Radiant CMS database mailer extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, radiant

I am trying to use the Database mailer extension for my Radiant CMS application.
I have followed the exact same steps mentioned here.
http://blog.aissac.ro/radiant/database-mailer-extension/
When I try to run the rake task to migrate I get this error. I am fighting with this for a while now. Where and what am I missing?
**Radiant version - 0.9

Database - mysql 5.0.75

Rails version - 2.3.5**

This is my error log.

http://gist.github.com/524155

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone made a fork of this extension and fixed this. I built on their work to fix a few additional bugs: https://github.com/mstalker/radiant-database-mailer-extension